# MySql Query error unknown syntax?

Tags: php, mysql

I have writen the following code but when i execute him i get this error: **Info table has not been createdYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ΟΟΞΏΟ ΞΆΟΞ�Ο   ', '13'), ('177', 'Ξ' at line 177** I have searched the code for errors but no luck... please help!!!

```
<?php   

// Connect to the file above here   
require "../connect_to_mysql.php";  

/*Index: 
        An index is a structure in a table that orders the data. It allows the database to access data quickly (In MySQL its implemented using B-tree algorithms).

Primary Key:
            This is an index that cannot be NULL, Primary Keys are used in building relationships between tables in a database. (an index is automatically created on the primary key). The difference between primary and ordinary keys is that there can be multiple keys, but only one primary key.

Unique:
        Unique and Index are same, the difference is, in Unique, duplicate are not allowed in any circumstances and that is enforced by database server.
*/

    $sqlCommand="CREATE TABLE info(
                 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                 add_info varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                 parent int(11) NOT NULL,
                 PRIMARY KEY(id)
                 )";

    if(mysql_query($sqlCommand)){
        echo "Your Info table has been created successfully";   
    }else{
        echo "Info table has not been created"; 
    }

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO info (id, add_info, parent) 
VALUES  ('1',  'Επεξεργαστής: INTEL CORE I7-2600 3.40 GHZ LGA1155 - BOX                     ', '1'),
('2',  'Οθόνη: LG E2251T-BN 22 LED                                                          ', '1'),
('3',  'Σκληρός Δίσκος: SEAGATE BARRACUDA LP ST1000DL002 1TB SATA2                          ', '1'),
('4',  'Σκληρός Δίσκος: OCZ OCZSSD2-1VTXPL30G 30GB VERTEX PLUS SATA2 2.5 SSD RETAIL         ', '1'),
('5',  'Μνήμη RAM: 2 x MUSHKIN 991586 2GB DDR3 PC3-10666 1333MHZ ESSENTIALS SERIES          ', '1'),
('6',  'Κάρτα Γραφικών: 2 x ASUS ENGTX550 TI DC/DI/1GD5 1GB PCI-E RETAIL                    ', '1'),
('7',  'Μητρική: ASUS P8P67 DELUXE REV3.0                                                   ', '1'),
('8',  'Κάρτα Ήχου: Intel High Definition Audio 10 channels                                 ', '1'),
('9',  'Κάρτα Δικτύου: Intel Pro 10/100/1000                                                ', '1'),
('10', 'Οπτικά Μέσα: LG GH22NS70 SECURE DISC DVD REWRITER BLACK BULK                        ', '1'),
('11', 'Case: ASUS VENTO TA-M21 BLACK                                                       ', '1'),
('12', 'Τροφοδοτικό: XILENCE 700W GAMING SERIES PSU                                         ', '1'),
('13', 'Πληκτρολόγιο: NILOX MULTIMEDIA KEYBOARD PS2/USB BLACK                               ', '1'),
('14', 'Ποντίκι: NILOX MT10 MOUSE OPTICAL USB BLACK SILVER                                  ', '1'),
('15', 'Ηχεία: NILOX SLIM MULTIMEDIA SPEAKERS 2.0 BLACK                                     ', '1'),
('16', 'Λειτουργικό Σύστημα: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Ελληνική/Αγγλική Έκδοση       ', '1'),
('17', 'Εγγύηση: 3 ΕΤΗ                                                                      ', '1'),
('18', 'Επεξεργαστής: INTEL CORE I7-960 3.20 GHZ LGA1366 - BOX                              ', '2'),
('19', 'Οθόνη: LG E2251T-BN 22 LED                                                          ', '2'),
('20', 'Σκληρός Δίσκος: SEAGATE BARRACUDA LP ST1000DL002 1TB SATA2                          ', '2'),
('21', 'Σκληρός Δίσκος: KINGSTON SV100S2D/64G SSDNOW V100 64GB DESKTOP BUNDLE               ', '2'),
('22', 'Μνήμη RAM: KINGSTON KHX1600C9D3K3/6GX DDR3 6GB (3X2GB) PC12800 1600MHZ HYPERX GENESIS TRIPLE CHANNEL KIT    ', '2'),
('23', 'Κάρτα Γραφικών: PNY NVIDIA QUADRO 2000 1GB PCI-E RETAIL                                                     ', '2'),
('24', 'Μητρική: ASUS SABERTOOTH X58 RETAIL                                                                         ', '2'),
('25', 'Κάρτα Ήχου: Realtek 8110SC Gigabit LAN controller featuring AI NET2                                         ', '2'),
('26', 'Κάρτα Δικτύου: Gigabit LAN controller Marvell 88E8056 PCIe Gigabit LAN controller featuring AI NET2         ', '2'),
('27', 'Οπτικά Μέσα: LG GH22NS70 SECURE DISC DVD REWRITER BLACK BULK                                                ', '2'),
('28', 'Case: ASUS VENTO TA-M21 BLACK                                                                               ', '2'),
('29', 'Τροφοδοτικό: L&C LC-8600BTX 600W ULTRA SILENT 120MM FAN ROHS SAFETY                                         ', '2'),
('30', 'Πληκτρολόγιο: NILOX MULTIMEDIA KEYBOARD PS2/USB BLACK                                                       ', '2'),
('31', 'Ποντίκι: NILOX MT10 MOUSE OPTICAL USB BLACK SILVER                                                          ', '2'),
('32', 'Ηχεία: NILOX SLIM MULTIMEDIA SPEAKERS 2.0 BLACK                                                             ', '2'),
('33', 'Λειτουργικό Σύστημα:Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Ελληνική Έκδοση 64bit                                  ', '2'),
('34', 'Εγγύηση: 3 ΕΤΗ                                                                                              ', '2'),
('35', 'Επεξεργαστής: AMD PHENOM II X4 955 3.2GHZ QUAD CORE BLACK BOX EDITION                                       ', '3'),
('36', 'Οθόνη: LG E2251T-BN 22 LED                                                                                  ', '3'),
('37', 'Σκληρός Δίσκος: SEAGATE BARRACUDA LP ST1000DL002 1TB SATA2                                                  ', '3'),
('38', 'Μνήμη RAM: 2 x MUSHKIN 991586 2GB DDR3 PC3-10666 1333MHZ ESSENTIALS SERIES                                  ', '3'),
('39', 'Κάρτα Γραφικών: ASUS EAH6670/DI/1GD3 1GB PCI-E RETAIL                                                       ', '3'),
('40', 'Μητρική: ASUS M5A87                                                                                         ', '3'),
('41', 'Κάρτα Ήχου: VIA VT1818 8-Channel High Definition Audio CODEC                                                ', '3'),
('42', 'Κάρτα Δικτύου: Realtek 8111E Gigabit LAN (10/100/1000Mbit/s)                                                ', '3'),
('43', 'Οπτικά Μέσα: LG GH22NS70 SECURE DISC DVD REWRITER BLACK BULK                                                ', '3'),
('44', 'Case: ASUS VENTO TA-M21 BLACK                                                                               ', '3'),
('45', 'Τροφοδοτικό: L&C LC-8600BTX 600W ULTRA SILENT 120MM FAN ROHS SAFETY                                         ', '3'),
('46', 'Πληκτρολόγιο: NILOX MULTIMEDIA KEYBOARD PS2/USB BLACK                                                       ', '3'),
('47', 'Ποντίκι: NILOX MT10 MOUSE OPTICAL USB BLACK SILVER                                                          ', '3'),
('48', 'Ηχεία: NILOX SLIM MULTIMEDIA SPEAKERS 2.0 BLACK                                                             ', '3'),
('49', 'Λειτουργικό Σύστημα: Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium Ελληνική/Αγγλική Έκδοση                               ', '3'),
('50', 'Εγγύηση: 3 ΕΤΗ                                                                                              ', '3'),
('51', 'Τύπος τροφοδοτικού: Intel ATX 12V 2.3 & EPS 12V 2.92                                                        ', '4'),
('52', 'Κωδικός κατασκευαστή: TP-1500M                                                                              ', '4'),
('53', 'Μέγιστη Ονομαστική Ισχύς: 1500W                                                                             ', '4'),
('54', 'Σύνδεση: 1 x 24pin Main connector (600mm), 1 x ATX 12V 4+4pin connector (600mm), 1 x EPS 12V 8pin connector (600mm), 4 x PCI-E 6+2pin & PCI-E 6+2pin connectors (550mm + 150mm), 4 x Peripheral (550mm + 150mm + 150mm + 150mm), 4 x PCI-E 6+2pin connector (550mm) , 8 x Peripheral connectors (550mm + 150mm + 150mm +150mm) , 12 x S-ATA connectors (550mm + 150mm + 150mm + 150mm) , 1 x PATA to FDD adapter (100mm)                                                                                            ', '4'),
('55', 'Συσκευασία: Retail                                                                                          ', '4'),
('56', 'Εγγύηση: 5 χρόνια                                                                                           ', '4'),
('57', 'Ισχύς: 800 Watts                                                                                            ', '5'),
('58', 'ATX Connector: 1                                                                                            ', '5'),
('59', 'EPS Connector: 1                                                                                            ', '5'),
('60', 'PCI-E Connector: 4                                                                                          ', '5'),
('61', '4 Pin Peripheral Connector: 8                                                                               ', '5'),
('62', 'SATA Connector: 8                                                                                           ', '5'),
('63', 'Floppy Connector: 2                                                                                         ', '5'),
('64', 'MTBF: 100,000 ώρες                                                                                          ', '5'),
('65', 'Διαστάσεις: 15cm x 8,6cm x 16cm                                                                             ', '5'),
('66', 'Εγγύηση: 2 χρόνια                                                                                           ', '5'),
('67', 'Μοντέλο: RS-A00-AMBA-J3                                                                                     ', '6'),
('68', 'Τύπος: Intel ATX12V V2.3 / SSI EPS 12V V2.92                                                                ', '6'),
('69', 'Τάση εισόδου: 90~264V (Αυτόματα μεταβαλλόμενη)                                                              ', '6'),
('70', 'Ρεύμα εισόδου: 14A@115Vac, 8A@230Vac                                                                        ', '6'),
('71', 'Εύρος συχνότητας λειτουργίας εισόδου: 47 - 63Hz                                                             ', '6'),
('72', 'PFC: Active PFC >0.9                                                                                        ', '6'),
('73', 'Ισχύς καλού σήματος: 100 ~ 500ms                                                                            ', '6'),
('74', 'Χρόνος αναμονής: >17ms                                                                                      ', '6'),
('75', 'Απόδοση: 85% typically                                                                                      ', '6'),
('76', 'MTBF: >100,000 ώρες                                                                                         ', '6'),
('77', 'Προστασία: OVP / UVP / OCP / OPP / OTP / SCP                                                                ', '6'),
('78', 'Ισχύς εξόδου: 1000W                                                                                         ', '6'),
('79', 'Μέγιστη ισχύς εξόδου: 1200W                                                                                 ', '6'),
('80', 'Θερμοκρασία λειτουργίας: 0 ~ 40°C                                                                           ', '6'),
('81', 'Ψύξη: 135mm Ultra Silent Fan                                                                                ', '6'),
('82', 'Πιστοποιήσεις: SLI / 80 Plus Bronze                                                                         ', '6'),
('83', 'Συνδέσεις: M/B 20+4 Pin Connector x 1, CPU 4+4 Pin x 2, PCI-E 6+2 Pin x 6 / PCI-e Y cable x 2, (Ένας σύνδεσμος PCI-e 6+2 pins μετατρέπεται σε δυο PCI-e 6+2 pins), SATA x 9 / Περιφερειακά 4 pins x 6, 4 Pin Floppy x 1                     ', '6'),
('84', 'Διαστάσεις (Μ/Π/Υ): 150 X 165 X 86 mm                                                                       ', '6'),
('85', 'Εγγύηση: 5 χρόνια                                                                                           ', '6'),
('86', 'Τύπος Οθόνης: 25 ιντσών Wide LED                                                                            ', '7'),
('87', 'Μέγιστη Ανάλυση: 1920x1080                                                                                  ', '7'),
('88', 'Αναλογία οθόνης: 16:9                                                                                       ', '7'),
('89', 'Διαγώνιος: 25                                                                                               ', '7'),
('90', 'Χρόνος απόκρισης: 5 ms                                                                                      ', '7'),
('91', 'Γωνίες θέασης: Οριζόντια: 170μοίρες, Κατακόρυφα: 170 μοίρες                                                 ', '7'),
('92', 'Κοντράστ: 5000000:1                                                                                         ', '7'),
('93', 'Φωτεινότητα: 250 cd/τμ                                                                                      ', '7'),
('94', 'Σύνδεση: VGA, DVI-D, Component, Composite, Scart, HDMI, PC Audio in, Optical out, USB                       ', '7'),
('95', 'Πρόσθετα Χαρακτηριστικά: Teletext Remote Control, DVB-T / DVB-C MPEG4                                       ', '7'),
('96', 'Ενσωματωμένα ηχεία : 2x 5Watt SRS Surround X                                                                ', '7'),
('97', 'Διαστάσεις (W x D x H): 594,9 x 381,1 x 52,2 mm                                                             ', '7'),
('98', 'Βάρος: 4.5 Kg                                                                                               ', '7'),
('99', 'Εγγύηση: 2 χρόνια zero pixel                                                                                ', '7'),                    
('100', 'Μέγεθος οθόνης: Ευρεία οθόνη 23                                                                            ', '8'),
('101', 'Ανάλυση: 1920 x 1080                                                                                       ', '8'),
('102', 'Τεχνολογία Οθόνης: LED                                                                                     ', '8'),
('103', 'Γωνία θέασης (Οριζόντια/Κάθετη): 170 / 160                                                                 ', '8'),
('104', 'Χρώματα οθόνης: 16,7 εκατομμύρια                                                                           ', '8'),
('105', 'Brightness (Typical): 250 cd/m²                                                                            ', '8'),
('106', 'Contrast Ratio (Typical): Δυναμική αντίθεση 5000 000:1                                                     ', '8'),
('107', 'Response Time (Typical): 2 ms                                                                              ', '8'),
('108', 'Θύρες: D-sub, 1 x HDMI                                                                                     ', '8'),
('109', 'Προσαρμογή θέσης οθόνης: Κλίση                                                                             ', '8'),
('110', 'Ειδικά χαρακτηριστικά: Eco Saving, Multi Screen S / W, Samsung MagicAngle, Samsung MagicBright3, Samsung MagicColor, Χρονοδιακόπτης απενεργοποίησης, MagicTune, Λειτουργία προσαρμοσμένων πλήκτρων, Ρύθμιση μεγέθους εικόνας, DVI με HDCP', '8'),
('111', 'Διαστάσεις προϊόντος (με βάση, ΠxΥxΒ): 555.7 x 426.4 x 239.2 χιλ                                           ', '8'),
('112', 'Χρώμα: Γυαλιστερό μαύρο                                                                                    ', '8'),
('113', 'Εγγύηση: 2 χρόνια                                                                                          ', '8'),
('114', 'Μέγεθος Ορατής Επιφάνειας:30                                                                               ', '9'),
('115', 'Ανάλυση Οθόνης: 2560 x 1600                                                                                ', '9'),
('116', 'Μέγεθος κουκίδας: 0.2505 mm                                                                                ', '9'),
('117', 'Γωνίες θέασης: Οριζόντια: 170 μοίρες, Κατακόρυφα: 160 μοίρες                                               ', '9'),
('118', 'Κοντράστ: 1000:1(στατικό), 3000:1 (δυναμικό)                                                               ', '9'),
('119', 'Χρόνος Απόκρισης: 7 ms                                                                                     ', '9'),
('120', 'Φωτεινότητα: 370 cd/m²                                                                                     ', '9'),
('121', 'Είσοδος Σήματος: DVI-D, DisplayPort                                                                        ', '9'),
('122', 'Πρόσθετα Χαρακτηριστικά: Aντιθαμβωτικές και αντιστατικές επιστρώσεις, κάθετη κλίση -5° έως +35°, 5-port USB Hub', '9'),
('123', 'Kατανάλωση: 185 Watts (max)                                                                                ', '9'),
('124', 'Διαστάσεις (Π x Β x Υ): 69.4 x 27.6 x 48.9 cm                                                              ', '9'),
('125', 'Χρώμα: Μαύρο                                                                                               ', '9'),
('126', 'Βάρος: 13 kg (με τη βάση)                                                                                  ', '9'),
('127', 'Εγγύηση: 3 χρόνια                                                                                          ', '9'),    
('128', 'Chipset: Radeon HD 7970                                                                                    ', '10'),
('129', 'Process Technology: 28 nm                                                                                  ', '10'),
('130', 'PCB Form ATX                                                                                               ', '10'),
('131', 'Xρονισμός πυρήνα: 925 MHz                                                                                  ', '10'),
('132', 'Χρονισμός μνήμης: 5500 MHz                                                                                 ', '10'),
('133', 'Μέγεθος μνήμης: 3072 MB                                                                                    ', '10'),
('134', 'Memory Bus: 384 bit                                                                                        ', '10'),
('135', 'Card Bus PCI-E 3.0                                                                                         ', '10'),
('136', 'Τύπος μνήμης: GDDR5                                                                                        ', '10'),
('137', 'DirectX: 11                                                                                                ', '10'),
('138', 'OpenGL: 4.2                                                                                                ', '10'),
('139', 'Multi-view: 4                                                                                              ', '10'),
('140', 'Είσοδοι / Έξοδοι: HDMI Χ 1 / DVI-I Χ 1 / Mini DisplayPort Χ 2                                              ', '10'),
('141', 'Διαστάσεις: Υ=38 mm, Μ=285 mm, Π=126 mm                                                                    ', '10'),
('142', 'Εγγύηση: 3 έτη                                                                                             ', '10'),
('143', 'Chipset: GeForce GTX 590                                                                                   ', '11'),
('144', 'Τύπος Μνήμης: GDDR5                                                                                        ', '11'),
('145', 'Μέγεθος Μνήμης: 3072 MB                                                                                    ', '11'),
('146', 'Engine Clock: 1215 MHz                                                                                     ', '11'),
('147', 'Memory Clock: 3414 MHz                                                                                     ', '11'),
('148', 'Tεχνολογία επεξεργασίας: 40 nm                                                                             ', '11'),
('149', 'Δίαυλος μνήμης: 768 bit                                                                                    ', '11'),
('150', 'Toποθέτηση: PCI Express 2.0                                                                                ', '11'),
('151', 'Είσοδοι-Έξοδοι: HDMI, DisplayPort (με αντάπτορα), mini HDMI, μίνι DisplayPort, DVI-I, DVI-D, D-sub (μέσω αντάπτορα)', '11'),
('152', 'Μέγιστη ανάλυση: 2560 x 1600                                                                               ', '11'),
('153', 'Πρόσθετα χαρακτηριστικά: Πλήρης υποστήριξη για DirectX 11, OpenGL 4.1                                      ', '11'),
('154', 'Τροφοδοσία: Ελάχιστo 700W ή μεγαλύτερο τροφοδοτικό σύστημα με δύο 8-pin εξωτερικές συνδέσεις ρεύματος      ', '11'),
('155', 'Διαστάσεις: 43mm x 290mm x 125mm                                                                           ', '11'),
('156', 'Συσκευασία: Retail                                                                                         ', '11'),
('157', 'Εγγύηση: 3 χρόνια                                                                                          ', '11'),   
('158', 'Chipset : NVIDIA Quadro 4000                                                                               ', '12'),
('159', 'Μέγεθος μνήμης: 2 GB GDDR5                                                                                 ', '12'),
('160', 'Τύπος μνήμης: GDDR5 256-bit                                                                                ', '12'),
('161', 'Memory bandwidth: 89.6 GB/s                                                                                ', '12'),
('162', 'Μέγιστη κατανάλωση ισχύς: 142 W                                                                            ', '12'),
('163', 'Interface: PCI Express 2.0 16x                                                                             ', '12'),
('164', 'Έξοδοι: Dual-link DVI-I, 2 x display                                                                       ', '12'),
('165', 'Ελάχιστες απαιτήσεις συστήματος: PC συμβατό με Intel Pentium 4/Xeon ή AMD Opteron ή ανώτερο, ελεύθερη PCI Express x16 θύρα, Microsoft Windows Vista, XP, 2000, Linux ή Solaris, 1GB μνήμη συστήματος, 100MB διαθέσιμα στο δίσκο για πλήρη εγκατάσταση, οδηγός CD-ROM ή DVD-ROM, οθόνη με συμβατή σύνδεση VGA, DVI-I ή DisplayPort, ελάχιστη ισχύ τροφοδοτικού 500 (μεγαλύτερης ισχύς απαιτείται για διάταξη σε SLI)                                                                                        ', '12'),
('166', 'Πρόσθετα χαρακτηριστικά: NVIDIA SLI technology, Microsoft DirectX 11.0, OpenGL 4.0 και Shader Model 5.0    ', '12'),
('167', 'Συσκευασία: Retail                                                                                         ', '12'),
('168', 'Εγγύηση: 3 χρόνια                                                                                          ', '12'),       
('169', 'Μέγεθος: 4 X 4GB                                                                                           ', '13'),
('170', 'Τύπος μνήμης: PC3-12000                                                                                    ', '13'),
('171', 'Ταχύτητα διαύλου: 1333MHZ                                                                                  ', '13'),
('172', 'Διαθέσιμη CAS: 9-9-9-24                                                                                    ', '13'),
('173', 'Τάση λειτουργίας: 1.5V                                                                                     ', '13'),
('174', 'Σύστημα ψύξης: CORSA edition σύστημα ψύξης με MTCD Technology σε Racing Orange φινίρισμα                   ', '13'),
('175', 'Τεχνολογία: DBT Enhanced, Die-hard, Burn-in Technology                                                     ', '13'),
('176', 'Εγγύηση: Εφ'όρου ζωής                                                                                      ', '13'),
('177', 'Μέγεθος: 4096MΒ (2x 2048MB) Dual Channel Kit                                                               ', '14'),
('178', 'Τύπος Μνήμης: DDR3 SDRAM PC3-12800, 240pin DIMM                                                            ', '14'),
('179', 'Ταχύτητα Διαύλου: 1600 MHZ                                                                                 ', '14'),
('180', 'Timings: 9-9-9-24                                                                                          ', '14'),
('181', 'Σύστημα ψύξης: Παθητικό                                                                                    ', '14'),
('182', 'Πρόσθετα χαρακτηριστικά: δοκιμασμένη στα 1600MHz σε X58-based μητρικές με επεξεργαστή Corei7               ', '14'),
('183', 'Part Number: CMX4GX3M2A1600C9                                                                              ', '14'),
('184', 'Εγγύηση: Lifetime                                                                                          ', '14')
    ") or die (mysql_error());



?>
```

Comment: actualy there is no problem creating the table! The problem is inserting the data!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For item 176 you are inserting an apostrophe in the second column - this is causing mysql to fail by prematurely closing a quote.